# PHP inside <script> - issue with echo command

Tags: javascript, php, echo

I need a small help with correcting this login form script (a part of nicely-styled login form):

```
<script>
$('.input').focusin(function () {
    $(this).find('span').animate({ 'opacity': '0' }, 200);
});
$('.input').focusout(function () {
    $(this).find('span').animate({ 'opacity': '1' }, 300);
});
$('.login').submit(function () {
    $(this).find('.submit i').removeAttr('class').addClass('fa fa-check').css({ 'color': '#fff' });
    $('.submit').css({
        'background': '#2ecc71',
        'border-color': '#2ecc71'
    });
    $('.feedback').show().animate({
        'opacity': '1',
        'bottom': '-80px'
    }, 400);
    $('input').css({ 'border-color': '#2ecc71' });

<?php
    if($entered_username != $default_username || $entered_password != $default_password){
        echo "return false;";
}?>
});
```

The PHP echo command at the end is problematic, but I need to keep return false when incorrect data is sent from login form. The biggest problem is, that when I leave the "return false;" permanently in this script, login is not possible, message about bad credentials is shown.

Could you help me, please, how to fix it? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Read more about web basics.

Comment: your file is saved as.. .js or .php ?

Comment: u_mulder: what did I do wrong? Could you be more specific, please?

Comment: rummykhan: this script is placed in login.php, under the html part of login form

Comment: PHP does not know what is happening on a page once it has generated it. You have to **submit** the users input back to the server so PHP can validate that input. As you have it here, you expect PHP to know the user input when it is generating the input form.

Comment: ok, thank you trincot, it seems I've finally understood it.